# swift UITapGestureRecognizer not working on view

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I had to create a new thread bcoz it's driving me crazy and all the other answers online are exactly the same. I have done this countless of times but I cannot see what I am missing for the life of me. I am using a "test" view controller just to get the tap gesture working but it isn't working at all... I am fairly certain that I am setting this up correctly, as this is how I've always implemented it in the past: (yes, I have checked the box for isUserInteractionEnabled). I am even implementing this on a different viewcontroller this exact way and it is working...

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  }

  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasTapped))

    
  @objc func wasTapped() {
    print("tapped")
  }
}
```

I have also tried adding the parameters to wasTapped:

```
@objc func wasTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  print("tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are saying:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasTapped))
```

The problem is the last line:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasTapped))
```

You cannot just say `let tap` like that in the middle of nowhere. You are implicitly making an instance property. But you cannot initialize an instance property with a target of `self`, because `self` does not exist at the time an instance property is initialized. (I regard the fact that that code even compiles as a bug, and have reported it as such.)

Move that line to the start of `viewDidLoad`, like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasTapped))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Comment: Although the first answer was also correct, I am choosing this one because of the explanation. I wanted to learn why, not just how. This makes total sense and I feel silly for not thinking about that. Thank you.

Comment: @matt as target takes an Any? is it the case "self" is referring to the viewcontroller type here rather than the instance?

Comment: @jeh In the "buggy" version where the OP says `let tap` at the top level of the view controller, _yes_, that is exactly what `self` turns out to mean. That's the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasTapped(sender:)))
     tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 // Default value
     view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

@objc func wasTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to enable interaction if you want to use gesture recognizers for standard `UIView`'s

Add `view.isUserInteractionEnabled` = true in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This issue still occurs when isUserInteractionEnabled is set to true, FWIW. At least it does on iOS 15.4.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

take a view and set IBOutlet like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewTap: UIView!
```

Write pretty code on `viewDidLoad()` like:

```
tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.myviewTapped(_:)))
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
viewTap.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
viewTap.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

this method is calling when tap gesture recognized:

```
@objc func myviewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  if self.viewTap.backgroundColor == UIColor.yellow {
    self.viewTap.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
  }else{
    self.viewTap.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
  }
}
```